# Heartbleed - impact on iOS apps?

Tags: openssl, ios, heartbleed

Just heard about the heartbleed news over the internet for OpenSSL and wondering if it affects ios apps as well. My app uses openssl crypto library and thus the concern !

Any views in this regard would be much appreciated !

Venkat

Comment: You are the developer? If you used openssl 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f for TLS connections and compiled **without**    -DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS then you are probably vulnerable. [Test](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55249), then patch as required.

Comment: @scuzzy-delta.. I am not very familiar with the security but it turns out we indeed used an affected version. From what I read earlier on the web mostly, it appeared only web servers were affected but the link you shared says clients are affected as well. Thanks a lot.. much appreciated !